# One word for "a one-eyed person"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, compounds, italian

I've given an English children's story to a small group of Italian kids to read and perform. The story is about a boy who changes into a cat and makes friends with a one-eyed next-door neighbour; a grumpy-looking man who wears an eye patch.

The kids didn't really understand what "one-eyed" meant so I translated it in Italian as **[guèrcio](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_inglese/Italiano/G/guercio.shtml)**. But they didn't know what *that* word meant, so I explained to them that "a one-eyed man" was a person who could see only from one eye, and no, he wasn't a Cyclops.

Likewise in Italian there is the adjective **[mónco](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_inglese/Italiano/M/monco.shtml)** which can describe a person with an amputated limb (usually it's the arm).

Which got me thinking, if each of these two physical disabilities has its own word in Italian, why isn't there its equivalent in English? I suppose nowadays these terms would be judged to be insensitive and discriminating, but what about in the past?

Maybe there used to be words that meant: "one-eyed person" and "one-armed person", or perhaps something in slang?

Comment: _Luscus_ is the Latin word for a one-eyed person. There is no English word.

Comment: Slangy terms for one-armed and one-legged are _wingy_ and _peggy_ (or peg-leg). Both sometimes pronominalized as in Joe 'Wingy' Manone (jazz player) and Frank 'Peggy' Gadsby (stunt diver).

Comment: As a side note: also Italians generally use  periphrases for *one-eyed* such as *con un occhio solo*  or *cieco ad un occhio* for instance. Guercio is more literary than common usage, plus its two meanings (one-eyed and cross-eyed) may create misunderstanding.

Comment: "Cyclops" is probably the closest you can come in a word most people would understand.  But the word also implies "giant".

Comment: @HotLicks I've actually heard this a couple of times - mostly as a semi-rude joke about someone (not necessarily a blind person, also if you get an infection or a black eye or something, you may jokingly be called a cyclops). However it doesn't fit in the context of this question.

Comment: @HotLicks It also implies they have, and have only ever had, one eye, not that they had two eyes but lost (the use of) one for whatever reason.

Comment: Spanish uses [*tuerto*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tuerto) to mean “one-eyed” (whether noun or adjective), not for “twisted” as in English *tortuous* or Italian *torto*. That person can only see out of one eye: the other may be missing or simply blind. Iberian languages also have a single word (again, either as substantive or adjective) for lame: ES *cojo*, PT *coxo*, CA *coix*; all from L. *coxus* and unrelated to vulgar *cojón* or *cojonudo* from L. *coleus*, although many a **lame** pun has been made of the similarity between the two. I don’t think Italian has a *cojo* cognate, right?

Comment: Just as an aside: in French there is *borgne*, *manchot*, *unijambiste*, and even *cul-de-jatte* :)

Comment: My wife and I both think *tuerto* only means "missing one eye" and does not include the "having both eyes, but blind in one of them". (Although the Spanish Royal Academy seems to [agree with you](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=tuerto).) We're both Mexican, maybe this varies from country to country?

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena You never know what’s under the eyepatch de un pirata tuerto. :)  I guess I wouldn’t call someone *tuerto* who seemed like they had two working eyes but didn’t. But if they had one eye all mangled or always closed or covered up so you couldn’t see it, I would. *Tuerto* always feels like *medio-ciego* to me. Oddly, I cannot think of a word for “half-deaf”.  In contrast, “half-witted” and “half-wit” are both *tonto*. :)

Comment: King.  But only if you live in a particular kingdom. ;)

Comment: It speaks highly of a culture that doesn't focus on people's disabilities to the extent of not having a specific word for such a disability.

Comment: The closest you could come for a word for "one-eyed person" that would be understood by perhaps 50% of educated English speakers is *cyclops*.  If you exclude that option then some variation of "one-eyed" is the best you can do.

Comment: @HotLicks you've already said this in the comments earlier. And anyway, cyclops was a monster, would any English speaking person have called a man or woman who could only see from one eye that? As an insult, maybe.  I was curious if there used to be a term either formal or in slang.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is ***monoculus*** for a one-eyed person but *OED* says that it is obsolete.

> †**2**. A one-eyed person or creature. *Obs.*

Etymology from *OED*:

> < post-classical Latin *monoculus* the caecum (1363 in Chauliac), a one-eyed person or creature (7th cent.; from 12th cent. in British sources), irregularly < ancient Greek *μονο-* mono- *comb. form* + classical Latin *oculus* .
>
> <sub>The word is perhaps attested earlier in sense A. 2 as a surname, Simon *Monoculus* (1212), though it is unclear whether this is to be interpreted as Middle English or post-classical Latin.</sub>

---

For someone who is blind in one eye or wearing an eye-patch, it doesn't seem like there is a specific single word. (For example, there is *borgne* in French.)

However, there is again an obsolete word for this sense: ***purblind***.

> **2. †a.** Blind in one eye. *Obs.*

*[Urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Pirate-eyed)* mentions ***pirate-eyed*** as a slang term but it is described as a specific case:

> "Pirate-eyed" is a condition resulting from over use of the iPhone or similar device in the dark or dimly-lit environment whilst favoring one eye. The resulting condition causes a temporary focal imbalance akin to having a patch over an eye.

Comment: I would guess that "monoculus" is apt to be read as "mononucleosis".

Comment: Anything on "one-armed person"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: It could be *monobrachium* (Latin for *arm* is *brachium*) if we apply the same logic, but currently it is the name of an [animal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monobrachium). I also see the usage of "monobrachial homology" or "monobrachial chromosome" in biology. It looks like there isn't a word in English for a "one-armed person".

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Based on ermanen's input, a *monobrachial* refers to a chromosome with one "arm" in biology. Since *a(n) (congenital) amputee* is commonly used in English without necessarily implying brachiotomy, I wonder if *monobrachial-amputee* understood?

Answer (score 9):

A [monops](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/121577).

monops, n. and adj.

rare.

A. n.

> A one-eyed individual.

1743   tr. N. Andry Orthopædia II. iv. 89   There are some People who have one Eye so small that one would almost say they have only one, whence the Name of Myopia is given to this Deformity, as the Person who has it is called a Monops.

1842   J. Wilson Recreations Christopher North II. 138   A few years ago.., in a mine in Cornwall, after a descent of about one-third the bored earth's diameter, we were saluted by name by a grim Monops who had not seen the upper regions for years.

1858   R. J. MacGeorge Tales, Sketches & Lyrics 191   Ardlaw rushed from the unlucky messuage with only one eye... Thus mutilated, mother Church..would have nothing to say to the monops.

1875   G. Meredith Beauchamp's Career xlv, in Fortn. Rev. 18 593   He would have been a Nelson of politics, if he had been a monops, with an excuse for not seeing.

1900   W. A. N. Dorland Illustr. Med. Dict. 396/1   Monops, a fetus having but a single eye.

B. adj.

> That has only one eye; one-eyed.

1857   R. G. Mayne Expos. Lexicon Med. Sci. (1860)    Monops, having but one eye: one-eyed.
1993   J. Peck Argura 62   Monops, monoglot, monosandalos—plenitude in a point.

---

A monophthalmic, derived from adjective [monophthalmic](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/121528) and medical condition monophthalmia.

monophthalmic, adj.
rare.

> Having only one eye; one-eyed.

1857   J. W. Donaldson Christian Orthodoxy 356   The belief in Cyclopian or monophthalmic deities.

1865   Sat. Rev. 16 Sept. 355/2   St. Jerome was equally explicit about the existence of the Phœnix and monophthalmic men.
1995   Times Higher Educ. Suppl. (Nexis) 1 Sept. 23   The deeper reading that sees the monophthalmic Cyclops as holding up a mirror to the Greeks' own cultural..deficiencies.

Source: Oxford English Dictionary

Comment: Not everyone has access to the OED, for example me! Could you copy and paste the definition of [monops](http://findwords.info/term/monops), please?

Comment: It wasn't free for everyone? I don't have an account, either. OK, as you wish.

Comment: No, when I click on the link I just see the home page :(

Comment: Anything on "one-armed person"?