# Why "monatomic" and not "monoatomic"?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, orthography, prefixes, word-formation

"Mono" means singular, and "atomic" stands for the atom. So combining them will give a single atom - "monatomic".

But why is this so? Why can't it be "monoatomic"?

[Meaning](https://www.lexico.com/definition/monatomic):

> Consisting of one atom.

Searching gives me this:

> Monoatomic (monatomic) [source](http://www.chem.ucla.edu/%7Eharding/IGOC/M/monoatomic.html)

In which monoatomic is the main word form. I could not find anything else online about this dual usage.

Comment: ... Alpha decay.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Isn't it omega decay?

Comment: Related in chemistry.SE: [Why "monoxide" but not "diodine"?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/145029/why-monoxide-but-not-diodine)

Comment: @Acccumulation I think it's actually omicron, but that might be better avoided.

Comment: See also kilohm and megohm (instead of kiloohm and megaohm).

Comment: Most English diphthongs are metastable at best having high energies of formation, small absorption cross sections, and short half-lifes.

Comment: @PhilSweet -- My experience has been that most dips have low energy, whether they are wearing thongs or not.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/121118?redirectedFrom=monatomic#eid)* says that *monatomic* is formed within English, by compounding; probably modelled on a French lexical item and provides the etymology below:

> < mono- *comb. form* + atomic *adj.*, probably after French ***monatomique*** (A. M. Gaudin 1833, in *Ann. de chim. et de physique* 52 115)

However, *OED* includes both forms:

> 1800s– **monatomic**, 1800s– **monoatomic**.

Today, in French, the form *[monoatomique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoatomique)* is used. However, it appears that the earliest form used in French was *monatomique* and it was first used by [A. M. Gaudin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marc_Antoine_Auguste_Gaudin) (a French chemist) in 1833. The French etymology dictionary from *Centre national de ressources textuelles et lexicales* (CNRTL) includes [the same origin](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/monoatomique) (as *OED*) but doesn't list the early form *monatomique*. However, you can find Gaudin's publications and the usage of *monatomique* in Google Books by searching "[monatomique Gaudin](https://www.google.com/search?q=monatomique%20Gaudin&rlz=1C1VDKB_enCA994CA994&biw=1536&bih=688&tbm=bks&ei=wLPCYrXWA92Dur4P9cW3iAY&ved=0ahUKEwi1tpXa9t74AhXdgc4BHfXiDWEQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=monatomique%20Gaudin&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQAFgAYMABaABwAHgAgAEAiAEAkgEAmAEAoAECoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-books)". In English, *monatomic* was first used in 1848 (per *OED*) and it was based on French *monatomique*, the earlier form. Here is the earliest citation from *OED*:

> Monatomic gases [Ger. *einatomige Gase*]. 
> H. Watts tr. L. Gmelin *Hand-bk. Chem.* I. 53

The prefix *mon-* is an alternative form of *mono-* and *OED* mentions "before a vowel or h usually **mon-**." for the combining form *mono-.* I believe the formation with *mon-* is even more strict if the second element starts with the vowel 'o', like *monoculus*<sup>[*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/234639/one-word-for-a-one-eyed-person/234641#234641)</sup>. There isn't the form *monooculus* but *OED* includes the form *monoculos* (from 1500s) as well.

*[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_prefixed_with_mon-)* lists some other words prefixed with *mon-* (you can find more on *OED*):

- monarchy

Note: *Monarchy* is an interesting case as the prefix *mon-* is not easily discernible and it is not a technical term. *Monarchy* is a borrowing, partly from French *monarchie* and partly from Latin *monarchia* and the ultimate origin is ancient Greek *μοναρχία* government by a single ruler ( < *μονο-* mono- *comb. form* + *ἄρχειν* to rule + *-ία* -y suffix.)<sup>[OED]</sup> The word *monastery* has a similar etymological path and it is from Hellenistic Greek *μονάζειν* to live alone ( < ancient Greek *μόνος* mono- *comb. form* + *-άζειν* suffix).<sup>[OED]</sup>

- monaster

Note: The technical term *monaster* is very similar to *monastery* but has a different etymology, which is from *mono-* + *aster (n.)* (from Latin *aster*, < Greek *ἀστήρ* star).<sup>[OED]</sup>

- monarthritic
- monarthritis
- monarticular
- monaulic
- monantherous

Comment: The most interesting example to me is _monaural_, which became popular (in contradistinction to _binaural_) in the early 1950s, but eventually lost out to _monophonic_ (in contradistinction to _stereophonic_). I remember being mystified during the middle to late 1960s about why record covers were shortening "monaural" to "mono"—but, of course, they weren't.

Comment: @SvenYargs Interesting indeed. Surprisingly, _OED_ mentions that the term _monaural_ is now preferred to _monophonic_ in sound recording and reproduction. However, per [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=monaural%2Cmonophonic&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), _monophonic_ gained slight traction in recent years; despite _monaural_ having an additional original sense ("Of or relating to the use of one ear only") as well.

Comment: "probably after French *monatomique*". Wait, what? In French, we use [*monoatomique*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoatomique).

Comment: @EricDuminil It appears that the earliest form used in French was _monatomique_ and it was used by Gaudin (a French chemist) in 1833. The french etymology dictionary CNTRL mentions [the same origin](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/monoatomique) as well but doesn't include the early form _monatomique_. However, you can find his books and the usage of _monatomique_ in Google Books by searching "monatomique Gaudin". In English, _monatomic_ was first used in 1848 (per _OED_) so it was based on French _monatomique_, the earlier form.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that "monoatomic" is the British spelling version and "monatomic" is American. It is said that it is rare to see "monoatomic". But both are correct.

> According to [Ichacha - Monoatomic](https://eng.ichacha.net/mzj/monoatomic.html):
>
> > The British spelling Monoatomic is just as correct as the American spelling Monatomic— Popsracer 13:02, 8 Mar 2004 (UTC)

Comment: This does not answer your question, about the reason behind the difference. If you don't adjust, I must CV the question as an easily found reference gives an answer with which you're satisfied.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's not really how close-voting is supposed to work. NAA vote if you will, but close voting should be done in a Death of the Author sense. (If there's clarification in comments that makes a close-worthy question un-close-worthy, it should be edited into the question.) The presence or absence of an answer does not affect whether the question should be closed, even if that answer is by the OP.

Comment: I'm pretty sure *"monatomic"* is the usual BrE spelling (source: native BrE speaker that once studied chemistry). *"monoatomic"* if anything is archaic.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 From this answer, one can only deduce that the intended question was 'Are the variants "monatomic" and "monoatomic" both in use, and equally widespread?' Answering this requires only the reasonable use of general reference resources, for which CVing is recommended. // Here, ermanen (unlike DialFrost) answers the question as phrased, using a less easily available source. Hence, I have not CVd.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I've already not voted to close. I was hoping this answer would be deleted.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's what the Not an Answer flag, or a delete vote, is for.